# Evaluate multiple items using for()

Tags: php

I need to use a OR (||) operator in my for() statement but it's not working as expected.

I send 4 attachments. Two are inline images, the other two are actual attachments.

The problem is that it's only looping through the two inline images ($results['Related'])

I assume my solution is very simple but I am just not seeing it.

Here is my code:

```
# Check for attachments
if(isset($results['Related']) || isset($results['Attachments']))
{
    if(isset($results['Related']))
    {
        $attachment_type = $results['Related'];
    }
    elseif(isset($results['Attachments']))
    {
        $attachment_type = $results['Attachments'];
    }

    for($i = 0; ($i < count($results['Attachments']) || $i < count($results['Related'])); $i++)
    {
        # Format file name (change spaces to underscore then remove anything that isn't a letter, number or underscore)
        $filename = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $attachment_type[$i]['FileName']));

        /* LOTS MORE CODE HERE */
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I forgot tell you what the the problem was.

Comment: What is the issue you're seeing? There is no reason you can't use `||` in your for statement like that. Not sure if your issue is stemming from running count() on something that is not set or not though.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen your edit before I posted that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

There are several ways of doing it, but for maintainability and readability, I would go with an [`array_walk()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)-based solution:

```
$doLotsOfStuff = function(&$el) {
    $el['FileName'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $el['FileName']));

    // Your other code goes here.
};

if (isset($results['Related'])) {
    array_walk($results['Related'], $doLotsOfStuff);
}

if (isset($results['Attachments'])) {
    array_walk($results['Attachments'], $doLotsOfStuff);
}
```

**Edit:**

For older PHP versions that don't support anonymous functions, you can use a normal function instead:

```
function doLotsOfStuff(&$el) {
    $el['FileName'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $el['FileName']));

    // Your other code goes here.
}

if (isset($results['Related'])) {
    array_walk($results['Related'], 'doLotsOfStuff');
}

if (isset($results['Attachments'])) {
    array_walk($results['Attachments'], 'doLotsOfStuff');
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this will work for me. I need to loop it because there is alot more code inside the `for()` statement after the `$filename` line.

Comment: @Draven: Well that's quite an important detail that you completely left out of your question, don't you think? :-)

Comment: No problem.  In this case, I would advise you to use [`array_walk()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), instead.  I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: @Draven: I've updated with an `array_walk()` example.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I get `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` on the `$doLotsOfStuff = function(&$el)` line :(

Comment: @Draven: You must be using an older PHP version that doesn't support anonymous functions.  I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked it up. You have it backwards though. `array_walk($results['Related'], 'doLotsOfStuff');` and there is also a typo. There is a lower-case N in your first `$el['FileName']`. When you make those changes I'll make this as answered. Thank you!

Comment: @Draven:  Good catch on the argument order; that was left over from my `array_map()` answer (PHP is notorious for not having consistent argument orders).  I've made the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Do it separately.

```
if(isset($results['Related']) {
  foreach ($results['Related'] as &$el) {
    $el['FileName'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $el['FileName']));
  }
}

if(isset($results['Attachments']) {
  foreach ($results['Attachments'] as &$el) {
    $el['FileName'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $el['FileName']));
  }
}
```

Comment: this isn't necessarily equivalent, but I suspect it's what the OP actually wants

Comment: @tobyodavies Yep, only except the OP omitted the code using `$filename` after `$filename = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to sum the counts?

I'm guessing `count($results['Attachments'])` is 2, and `count($results['Related'])` is also 2, since you said you send two of each. In that case, it would only run the first two times.

Sounds like you need something like this:

```
# Check for attachments
if(isset($results['Related']) || isset($results['Attachments']))
{
    $count = 0;

    if(isset($results['Related']))
    {
        $attachment_type = $results['Related'];
        $count += count($results['Related']);
    }

    if(isset($results['Attachments']))
    {
        $attachment_type = $results['Attachments'];
        $count += count($results['Attachments']);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        # Format file name (change spaces to underscore then remove anything that isn't a letter, number or underscore)
        $filename = preg_replace('/[^0-9,a-z,\.,_]*/i', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $attachment_type[$i]['FileName']));
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that won't work either because of the $attachment_type. But I see what you're doing and I should be able to get that to work by adding more if() statements

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `count` on something that is not set, just count `$attachment_type` itself as that is guaranteed to be set.